# Bootstrap CSS vertical spacing disappears when columns get stacked

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like some form fields to be side by side when there's width available on the client, and stacked neatly when there isn't.  It's almost working, but not quite "stacked neatly".  Here's the markup ...

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="text" placeholder="State" class="form-control" ng-model="family.state">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Zip" class="form-control" ng-model="family.zip">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="family.listAddress">List address</input>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the wide result, which is as desired:

[image: good]

But here's the narrow result which is not quite right (because of the missing vertical space):

[image: not terrible, but wrong]

Answer (score -1):

What does your CSS look like? You can add a class to all of these divs and apply a simple    `margin: 5px;` and that could solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  It's bootstrap with no additions.  I guess I could do a special kind of col-md-*, but do you think that bootstrap should handle this out of the box?

Comment: that could have been better off as a comment. Bootstrap is a responsive framework and has hierarchies of spacing, colors and every UI component. setting it down right to 5px is a bad-static way to fix things.